# Why does this pointer point to nowhere?

Tags: .net, pointers, visual-c++, c++-cli, v8

I'm trying to add functionality to the v8sharp project and I'm having some issues (I'm not very good at C++-CLI so I'm pretty sure the issue lies in my lack of C++-CLI abilities rather than misusing v8.)

v8value.cpp:

```
v8sharp::V8FunctionWrapper^ V8ValueWrapper::WrapFunction(v8::Handle<v8::Value> value) {

  // Now we use the wrapper to make this safe to use
  // this works
  Console::WriteLine("IsFunction-First: {0}", value->IsFunction());
                // persistent so it doesn't get garbage collected
  v8::Persistent<v8::Value> pval(value);
                // create a function wrapper
  V8FunctionWrapper^ bla = gcnew V8FunctionWrapper(pval);
  return bla;
 }
```

Which should take a `v8Handle<v8::Value>` which contains a function (it always will because of what calls this function) and returns a nice .net wrapper so we can use it in my C# project.

The problem lies here
v8functionwrapper.cpp:

```
#include "v8functionwrapper.h"
#include "v8value.h";


v8sharp::V8FunctionWrapper::V8FunctionWrapper(v8::Persistent<v8::Value> value)
{
    // is this wrong? 
 this->_value = &value;
     // still true
 Console::WriteLine("Constructor: {0}", (*this->_value)->IsFunction());


}

// This function is called by C# and triggers the javascript function
Object^ v8sharp::V8FunctionWrapper::Call([ParamArray]array<Object ^> ^ args)
{
 // Get a refence to the function
 Console::WriteLine("Cast 2");
    // MEMORY VIOLATION: the _value no longer points to a valid object :(
 Console::WriteLine("IsFunction: {0}", (*this->_value)->IsFunction());
 Console::ReadLine();
-- snip --

}
```

v8functionwrapper.h:

```
#pragma once
#include "v8.h"

using namespace System;
using namespace System::Reflection;

namespace v8sharp {
public ref class V8FunctionWrapper 
{
public:
 delegate bool V8FunctionCallback(array<Object ^> ^ args);
 Object^ v8sharp::V8FunctionWrapper::Call([ParamArray]array<Object ^> ^ args);
 v8::Persistent<v8::Value> Unwrap();
 V8FunctionWrapper(v8::Persistent<v8::Value> value);
 ~V8FunctionWrapper();
 !V8FunctionWrapper();

private:
 V8FunctionCallback^ _callback;
 v8::v8<Persistent::Value>* _value;

};
}
```

Evident from this line (debug code):
`Console::WriteLine("IsFunction: {0}", (*this->_value)->IsFunction());`
The pointer _value is no longer valid and causes an exception. Why does my pointer invalidate? Is it because I'm pointing to an argument in the constructor and that gets deleted? If so how do I get a pointer to it that won't disappear. Keep in mind this is a .net class so I can't mix and match native types into it.

Comment: Why is that asterisk in there?

Comment: I'm curious as to why you're using `(*this->_value)->IsFunction()`.

Comment: _value is a `v8::v8<Persistent::Value>* _value;` because you can't mix and match native/managed types but you can use pointers to native types in managed classes. I just put that there to see if would work if I just put the pointer in a variable.

Comment: The first two comments are hilarious :)

Comment: Instead of `(*this->_value)`, why not write `value`?

Comment: I was testing if the pointer thing worked (No reason why it wouldn't). That's not where the error is though. Error is in the ` Object^ v8sharp::V8FunctionWrapper::Call` function where all I have this the pointer

Comment: Normally that Console::WriteLine wouldn't even be there. It's just to test if everything is set it what it should be

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to instantiate a new v8::Persistent value as a member of your class because the one you are passing in is created on the stack and will be destroyed as soon as WrapFunction returns. Also don't forget to delete _value when your object is destroyed.

```
v8sharp::V8FunctionWrapper::V8FunctionWrapper(v8::Persistent<v8::Value> value)
{
    this->_value = new v8::Persistent<v8::Value>(value)
}
```

Comment: Almost right except you don't want `gcnew` here but rather plain new.

Comment: This creates this error:
`Error 4 error C2726: 'gcnew' may only be used to create an object with managed type` EDIT: thanks logan :P

Comment: @Logan - thanks I did realise that and edited it as soon as I'd posted.
@Chris - swap the gcnew for a new :)

Comment: Fixed the problem thanks :). Now there's another problem but that's another story :P